# MaterialComponents theme breaks TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, material-components

I'm migrating my app to MaterialComponents themes. I have an activity with a TabLayout inside a Coordinator layout with a scrolling behavior, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:elevation="0dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It was working fine with AppCompat themes. I have 3 tabs, and the 3 tabs titles were displayed correctly in the TabLayout.

Now I have three issues:

- the TabLayout's text is black, as if the android:theme was ignored
- there's no longer a selected tab indicator (it was a bar in my accent color)
- only 2 of my 3 tabs are displayed

  - on startup, they are aligned right
  - if I scroll the view pager to display the middle page, I still only have 2 tabs displayed in the TabLayout, but now one is aligned left and the other is aligned right
  - if I scroll again to show the 3rd tab, there are still only 2 tabs title is the TabLayout, and now both are aligned left

What is going on here?

EDIT: I understood the issue better: seems it's "just" a color issue. The selected tab title color is the same as the background, thus I can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the answer: the main problem was that I was using android:theme rather than style to apply the TabLayout style.

Now I'm doing this:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/AppTheme.TabLayout"/>
```

And here's AppTheme.TabLayout:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TabLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorOnPrimary</item>
</style>
```

As specified [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/tab-layout/), I shouldn't have to create my own style to override the tabIndicatorColor as it should already take the colorOnPrimary I defined in my colors.xml. Seems there's a bug.